# Installing django-import-export raises ValueError

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm trying to install django-import-export.
Python version = 3.6
Django version = 1.10.3

When I entered: `pip install django-import-export`

It says:

`raise ValueError("cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern")
ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I think it has something to do with tablib.I tried installing tablib(`pip install tablib`).

Comment: is this the full stack trace?http://imgur.com/V24kaMe

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/254